# I have a text file (12 column and 10K rows). I want to load data from text file and feed to a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file (12 column and 10K rows). I want to load data from text file and feed to a 2D array. The text file contains data as below-
`(3,9,16,40,41,44)
(15,25,26,41,45,46)
(1,6,21,27,39,48) 
(7,20,26,29,39,42) 
(17,23,25,29,30,43)`

I know how to import data from text file. I was trying to code

```
file = open('Data.txt','r')
input=[]
for line in file.readlines():
    input.append(line)
print (input)
```

but get the output like this
`['(3,9,16,40,41,44) \n', '(15,25,26,41,45,46)\n', '(1,6,21,27,39,48)\n', '(7,20,26,29,39,42)\n', '(17,23,25,29,30,43)\n']`

How can I eliminate `'` and `\n` from the output and can get the output like below
`[(3,9,16,40,41,44), (15,25,26,41,45,46), (1,6,21,27,39,48), (7,20,26,29,39,42), (17,23,25,29,30,43)]`

I tried to use
`import numpy as np
input = np.loadtxt("Data.txt", dtype='str')
print(input)`

but the output is quite similar as data is read as a string.
any suggestion is highly appreciated.-Thanks

Comment: The import code you have is giving you lines, these are textual information (strings) so not for use as numbers. Also, they contain a linebreak (newline, `'\n'`). Your question boils down to the task of parsing these strings into tuples or lists of numbers.

Comment: Dtype is the output dtype.  Use none, to detect.

Comment: `loadtxt` (and similar functions) are intended for text files with just the numbers and delimiter (like comma), but no () or [].  Without those it's simple matter of splitting the lines on the delimiter and converting each string to a number.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open('Data.txt','r') as file:
    result = [tuple(map(int, line.strip(' \n()').split(','))) for line in file]

print(result)
```

---

```
[(3, 9, 16, 40, 41, 44),
 (15, 25, 26, 41, 45, 46),
 (1, 6, 21, 27, 39, 48),
 (7, 20, 26, 29, 39, 42),
 (17, 23, 25, 29, 30, 43)]
```

I believe that is your desired output.

The first step is to strip whitespace and parentheses (`line.strip(' \n()')`). Then, split it into a list on commas (`.split(',')`), then turn the list of strings into a tuple of ints (`tuple(map(int, )`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple way to do it that uses [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('Data.txt','r') as file:
    data = [literal_eval(line) for line in file]

print(data)
```

Printed output:

`[(3, 9, 16, 40, 41, 44), (15, 25, 26, 41, 45, 46), (1, 6, 21, 27, 39, 48), (7, 20, 26, 29, 39, 42), (17, 23, 25, 29, 30, 43)]`